# Ajax plugin causing posts not to load

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

In effort to solve the problem of a music player reloading every time the page is navigated to, I decided to Ajax-ify my new wordpress site. I tried doing it by hand but had a problem with loading, so I installed the Advanced AJAX Page Loader plugin but am having the same issue. Does anyone know what's causing it?

When this plugin is active, pages with post queries included don't return any results. It will load the page, title and category links, but the actual thumbnails linking to the individual posts don't load. Deactivate the plugin and it all loads normally.

Here's an example. Load the page initially (you will see the items, then click the menu link to activate the ajax. The items disappear

http://dev.kristinachilds.com/portfolio/

I went to the support forum for the plugin but they're not responding, so hopefully someone here will have an idea.

Comment: Honestly, the code for that plugin is poor. It's probably one of the reasons why it doesn't work right for you. Sorry to say. All that does is perform an ajax request to get the content of the `entire page`, then it tries to use it's own DOM parsing code to extrapolate the pieces `it thinks you need`. This is where the problem lay. Also, I've inspected the DOM, and the elements are there, but they're all `display:none; opacity:0;`. Last, your click events aren't delegated, they're static, so any future elements will not fire the events. Lots here to do.

Comment: Ugh. Well this is my first foray into ajax. I started out following the instructions [here](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/81-ajaxing-a-wordpress-theme/) from Chris Coyier with similar results. Is there another tutorial or some sort of instruction online that would work better you would recommend?

Comment: I think this question falls under the close reason `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.` . . . . I'd try to research for an Ajaxified Theme, I mean, I think will be easier to have a theme that's designed to work with AJAX. (ps: themeforest themes use to be very hard to adapt...)

Comment: lol aren't /all/ questions on stackoverflow "why isn't this code working?" ;)